# babel with russian and english language

Tags: languages, babel

I need to use Russian in my article, but the default language has to be English. 
How do I do this?

I use:

```
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

Result: all chapter names and date are in Russian.

Change to:

```
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
```

Result is the same.

Change to:

```
\usepackage[russian,ukrainian,english]{babel}
```

Result: all chapter names and dates are in Ukrainian.

It looks like `english` is ignored. How to fix this?

Here the code which doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{article}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}

\usepackage[russian,ukrainian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{A}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide an MWE? I was quite convinced that the last specified language should be the default.

Comment: It's working if I delete ,english from the first line, but then I can't use russian...

Comment: You can't use russian with `\selectlanguage` etc? That would be a bug in my eyes.

Answer (score 24):

The problem is in the `english` option in `\documentclass`. Let's see what happens:

1. `english` is a global option, so that it's passed to *every* package
2. the list of local options to `babel` is `russian`, `ukrainian`, `english`.

So `babel` gets first the global option `english` and loads the language file `english.ldf`; then it loads `russian.ldf` and `ukrainian.ldf` but does nothing with `english`, because it has already read that option.

Consequence: the last loaded language is Ukrainian.

Remedies: don't put language options in `\documentclass` if you plan to load `babel` with multiple languages, or specify *all* languages, in the desired order, as options to `\documentclass`.

Comment: With newer version of `babel`, one can specify `main=<language>` in the options to `babel`, so to establish `<language>` as the main document one independently of its position.

Comment: Thank you for this response. The assignment via document was the problem for me as well. Infuriating.

Answer (score 22):

To be a bit more explicit, after my comments above. According to the Wikibooks on LaTeX and `babel`, you can:

---

"If you call babel with multiple languages:

```
\usepackage[languageA,languageB]{babel}
```

then the last language in the option list will be active (i.e. languageB), and you can use the command

```
\selectlanguage{languageA}
```

to change the active language. You can also add short pieces of text in another language using the command

```
\foreignlanguage{languageB}{Text in another language}
```

Babel also offers various environments for entering larger pieces of text in another language:

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{languageB}
  Text in language B. This environment switches all language-related 
  definitions, like the language 
  specific names for figures, tables etc. to the other language.
\end{otherlanguage}
```

The starred version of this environment typesets the main text according to the rules of the other language, but keeps the language specific string for ancillary things like figures, in the main language of the document. The environment hyphenrules switches only the hyphenation patterns used; it can also be used to disallow hyphenation by using the language name 'nohyphenation'.

The babel manual provides much more information on these and many other options."

---

So far my citation and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the answers here have put me on the right track (it was not clear for me at first read). So I will try to clarify for other users.

By testing I have found out that:

- the order of the languages in `\usepackage[russian,ukrainian,english]{babel}` is not important if you use `\selectlanguage{}` afterwards.
- when you want to use Russian write `\selectlanguage{russian}`, after this everything that is generated will be in Russian (e.g. "Contents" will be "Содержание"). When you are ready with your Russian Text, write `\selectlanguage{english}` and everything  afterwards will be in English

I hope that I was also of some help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give all the language options to the document class.  This will pass them to any other packages you load, if they support Russian or Ukrainian.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,russian,ukrainian,english]{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{babel}
  \babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=Common]{CMU Serif}
  \babelfont{sf}[Ligatures=Common]{CMU Sans Serif}
  \babelfont{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}
\else
  \usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{babel}
\fi

\babeltags{english=english}
\babeltags{ukrainian=ukrainian}
\babeltags{russian=russian}

\begin{document}

\title{In \languagename, \textukrainian{\languagename} and
       \textrussian{\languagename}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Title-casing the `\languagename` is trickier than it looks, as the macro is not fully-expandable.