# biblatex biber non-latin (cyrillic) UTF-8 names

Tags: biblatex, unicode, biber, input-encodings, cyrillic

I am back where I was when I switched from stock `bibtex` to `biblatex-biber`: (cyrillic) **non-latin UTF-8 names** in the bibliography. It's why I started using `biber` in the first place, the same would happen with other non-latin alphabets, probably.

The combination of `"mwe.tex"` and `"mwe.bib"` below puts a lot of `\x{....}` macros in `"mwe.bbl"`:

```
\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{entry}{nty}
    \entry{aam:toa}{inproceedings}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=04494761d938ce066050ccda372dcbfb}{A.A.\bibnamedelimi Markov}{A\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=04494761d938ce066050ccda372dcbfb}{A.A.\bibnamedelimi Markov}{A\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \list{location}{1}{%
        {Moscow, Leningrad}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
{\x{0420}\x{041e}\x{0421}\x{0421}\x{0418}\u{\x{0418}}\x{0421}\x{041a}\x{0410}\x{042f} \x{0410}\x{041a}\x{0410}\x{0414}\x{0415}\x{041c}\x{0418}\x{042f}~\x{041d}\x{fffd}\x{fffd}\x{0423}\x{041a}}%
      }
```

giving an equal number of errors:

```
INFO - Converting UTF-8 to TeX macros on output to .bbl
"\x{0420}" does not map to ascii at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.0/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 490.
...
"\x{041a}" does not map to ascii at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.0/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 517.
```

However, when i edit `"mwe.bbl"` and replace instead:

```
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
{РОССИЙСКАЯ АКАДЕМИЯ~НАУК}%
```

it works as intended.

The `"mwe.tex"` is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=reading,safeinputenc=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\cite{aam:toa}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and `"mwe.bib"`:

```
@PREAMBLE{                 "\RequireBiber[2]"                        }
@String{         РАН   =   {РОССИЙСКАЯ АКАДЕМИЯ~НАУК}                }
@InProceedings{                                              aam:toa ,
              author   =   {A.A.~Markov}                             ,
               title   =   {The Theory of Algorithms}                ,
           booktitle   =   {Trudy Mat. Inst. Steklov}                ,
                year   =   1954                                      ,
              volume   =   42                                        ,
               pages   =   {3--375}                                  ,
             address   =   {Moscow, Leningrad}                       ,
           publisher   =   РАН                                       ,
}
```

The question is how to make `biber` handle non-latin UTF-8 names without complaints.

(By the way, I have a *translation* of that "book", so this `BibTeX` entry is just to exemplify.)

Comment: Don't use the option `safeinputenc`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Otherwise, in the actual setting, involving a class, i get the initial errors (that i got with stock bibtex) `! LaTeX Error: Command \CYRR unavailable in encoding T1.`

Comment: Mr Fischer is right, safeinputenc=true will set the input encoding to ascii essentially. This may not work at all until you remove `safeinputenc`, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and switch to LuaTeX or XeTeX. See the biber manual for details on exactly these issues.

Comment: @PLK: Mrs. Fischer.

Comment: @sjbiaga: Then make a MWE that demonstrates your real problem. Using `safeinputenc` to solve it is the wrong way.

Comment: As Ulrike Fischer indicates your MWE compiles fine when the `safeinputenc` is removed.  What is the documentclass of your actual situation?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Apologies Mdme, I didn,t register the "e"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I excuse as well, I was just buying time to found an `MWE` with problems: I say till Saturday. The documentclass is `report` based. I cannot foresee, but it is upon `\end{document}` (redefined) when `99postamble.tex` is `\input`ed, and where `\printbibliography` is invoked. The tail output are these lines: `...) (./99postamble.tex [64]
Underfull \hbox (badness 2057) in paragraph at lines 18--18
[]\T1/txr/m/n/9 Bode A. and Dal Cin M. \T1/txr/m/it/9 Par-al-lel Com-puter Ar-c
hi-tec-tures: The-ory, Hard-ware, Soft-ware,
! LaTeX Error: Command \CYRR unavailable in encoding T1.`

Comment: OK, here it is, as simple as it gets: change or add languages, e.g., `\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}`, just have any list of `babel` languages with **middle** `russian`.

Comment: An exact problem with my comment is here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50635/babel-with-russian-and-english-language). It works for me using `\foreignlanguage` within `BibTeX` names. Should this be enough, or is it any `biber` solution around?

Comment: After all, when i replaced manually `\list{publisher}...`, the `mwe.bbl` worked *without* `\foreignlanguage` wrapping the UTF-8 text.

Comment: Seeing the last comment, the problem seems to be solved. As it's very localized, it will be closed.