# Greek characters instead of "et al."

Tags: bibliographies, greek

Problem: In the final pdf document I get greek letters "k. sun." instead of "et al." when citing articles, for instance "Garris k. sun". instead of "Garris et al". This refers to the text corpus, not the bibliography. The bibliography at the end of the document is fine.
I am using an identical preamble to a colleague of mine with the difference that I use `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}` because I need greek letters in my document. But I don't know what it has to do with the bibliography. 
I need to cite in APA style. For citing I use the `\citep` command.

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{appendix}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1.6in}
```

...

```
\bibliography{prova}{}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

...

Here an example from the bibliography:

```
@article{garris2002games,
  title={Games, motivation, and learning: A research and practice model},
  author={Garris, R. and Ahlers, R. and Driskell, J.E.},
  journal={Simulation \& gaming},
  volume={33},
  number={4},
  pages={441--467},
  year={2002},
  publisher={Sage Publications}
}
```

Here the result:

[image]

Comment: Can you expand your code to a minimal example? A bibliography item where authors are abbreviated is also needed.

Comment: Is your document in English with only some smaller parts in Greek?

Comment: Yes, some Rho's here and there to report data analysis.

Comment: There's no need to use the Greek option: just use `\rho` in math mode. Can you add an example of how you use Greek for getting a rho?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I could avoid that. I have been using     `\textgreek{r}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try to replace

```
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
```

with

```
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
```

But perhaps, if you just need to type some greek letters, why don't you type directly α, β, γ, &c. and compile with LuaLaTex ? You'll only have to use an opentype font that has greek letters — Latin Modern has.

Comment: It worked :) But although I am a new user of latex, I don't understand why... Why would the order in which I put them make a difference? 

And what is LuaLatex? Sorry for the newbie questions.

Comment: @ALaufer: This is how `babel` was built. See here for a short answer and a starting point for further reading: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50638/7417