# Why the item style has changed to dashed instead of bullets?

Tags: itemize, french

I'm writing a thesis in LaTeX whose main language is English, with also a French abstract at the beginning (I suppose this fact to be relevant).

Inside `\itemize`, all items are by default formatted as a dashed list, although I would like it to be a "normal" bullet list, (as it was at the beginning of writing).

I'm not sure about the exact moment when the whole formatting has changed, but I think it was with the addition of all the abstract and introduction parts (but I noticed that after).

If it is the case, why does it happen (and, of course, how can I fix it)?

Comment: use package `enumitem` then you can easily modify nearly everything.

Comment: Have you by any chance loaded the `babel` package with `french` as an option?

Comment: french changes the layout. Check the document about how to customize this http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/frenchb/frenchb.pdf.

Comment: @vl1131: didn't you forget to type ‘\selectlanguage{english}’ after the end of your abstract in french?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes

Comment: @UlrikeFischer your link has been useful; I discovered that it is the last loaded package to control the formatting, so I change to \usepackage[french,english]{babel} ; but it did not change anything.

Comment: From [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50635/babel-with-russian-and-english-language) it seems that, it the english package has been already loaded, changing the order within babel will not work; but I cannot find when the english package could be already loaded.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/frenchb/frenchb.pdf .

When french is the last loaded language in the document, all typographical rules are set "à la francaise".

To remove this (for me, undesired) behavior:

```
\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout}
```

Comment: If the document's main language is not French, just put the main language last in the options to `babel`.

Comment: @egreg as in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50635/babel-with-russian-and-english-language), this solution could be of no effect.